# awk and sed commands from batch Linux to Windows. How to convert it?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, awk, wireshark

In my recent project I want to make a script to convert a WireShark Output to show the bytes per time frame. With this I got the working script:

```
 ./tshark -r dumps/combinedOutput2.pcapng -T fields -e frame.time -e frame.len \
     | sed -e 's/\..*\t/\t/' \
     | awk -F"\t" '$1==last {sum += $2; next} {
         printf("%s  %8d bytes/s (%6.2f Mbit/s)\n",last,sum,sum*8/1024/1024);
         last=$1;sum=$2}'
```

In Windows (with the awk and sed commands from GNU Windows) the escapes for quotes and backslashes are different. However I am not able to convert it the right way and get the following error:

```
awk: {sed -e ^s/\.."\\t/\t/}
awk:            ^ backslash not last character on line  
tshark: An error occurred while printing packets: Invalid argument.
```

Can anyone help me with formatting this correctly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using https://www.cygwin.com you don't need the converting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing the `awk` single-quotes with double-quotes as below

```
 ./tshark -r dumps/combinedOutput2.pcapng -T fields -e frame.time -e frame.len \
     | sed -e 's/\..*\t/\t/' \
     | awk -F"\t" '$1==last {sum += $2; next} {
         printf("%s  %8d bytes/s (%6.2f Mbit/s)\n",last,sum,sum*8/1024/1024);
         last=$1;sum=$2}'
```

and escape the double-quotes within `"` using a `\`

```
 ./tshark -r dumps/combinedOutput2.pcapng -T fields -e frame.time -e frame.len \
     | sed -e 's/\..*\t/\t/' \
     | awk -F"\t" "$1==last {sum += $2; next} {
         printf(\"%s  %8d bytes/s (%6.2f Mbit/s)\n\",last,sum,sum*8/1024/1024);
         last=$1;sum=$2}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this got the problem fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Never execute an awk script from the command line in Windows, always execute it from a file to avoid having to deal with Windows nightmarish quoting rules. You also don't need sed when you're using awk.

Put this in `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ sub(/\..*\t/,"\t") }
$1==last {sum += $2; next}
{
    printf "%s  %8d bytes/s (%6.2f Mbit/s)\n", last, sum, sum*8/1024/1024
    last = $1
    sum = $2
}
```

and execute it as:

```
./tshark -r dumps/combinedOutput2.pcapng -T fields -e frame.time -e frame.len \
 | awk -f script.awk
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works very good and cleaner! I have one extra question though: how to add another row, with another Wireshark field such as "ip.dst" ?

Comment: That could mean one of several things. I suggest you post a followup question and remember to include concise, testable sample input (i.e. wireshark output) and the output you expect from the awk script given that input.